# Pass parameter from a custom php function to hook_block

Tags: 7, hooks, blocks

I have a hook_menu page callback. I want to use the argument which it receives in hook_block.

For example

```
function myCustomFunction($args) {

}

modulename_block() {
  // Use $args here
}
```

How can this be done. Is there a way I can pass this as a parameter.

Comment: This type of question shows up every now and then, so I tried writing a more canonical version of the question: [How do I pass data between "arbitrary code A" and "arbitrary code B"?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32354/how-do-i-pass-data-between-arbitrary-code-a-and-arbitrary-code-b/32355#32355)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this would be expected to work consistently; if your block relies on arguments built up from a particular page callback, then the block will only work on that page.

Having said that, if the page callback arguments are based on a known value, for example a node ID, then I can see how it might work for a particular path/set of paths.

Let's say this is your menu item in `hook_menu()`:

```
$items['my/path/%node'] = array(
  'title' => 'A title',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_some_function',
  'page arguments' => array(2)
);
```

And this is your code for `MYMODULE_some_function()`:

```
function MYMODULE_some_function($node) {
  $the_value = do_something_to($node);
}
```

In your `hook_block()` function you can grab the node ID out of the URL, load the node manually, and perform the same function on it that you have in `MYMODULE_some_function()`. For example:

```
function MYMODULE_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  // I've omitted the 'list' op, obviously you'll need to implement that yourself

  if ($op == 'view' && $delta == $the_delta) {
    // Check that we're on an appropriate page
    if (arg(0) == 'my' && arg(1) == 'path' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
      $nid = arg(2);

      $node = node_load($nid);

      $the_value = do_something_to($node);

      $block['content'] = $the_value;
    }
  }
}
```

You might want to centralise the code that runs `$the_value = do_something_to($node);` into it's own function so you're not repeating yourself.

Comment: i am sending Client time using JQuery and ajax as an argument.I want to display a message in the block depending on the current time.Say like a greeting message.I have some if conditions in my block where i compare the currentTime to display a message.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The block obviously won't be processed until the next page request when you make the AJAX call, so the block content would always be out of date (i.e. the result of the previous AJAX request, not the current). It sounds like you might just want to to manipulate the block directly on the client side and not bother sending it to the server